# Is there a tool to analyse if a C# and WPF project can be ported to Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a WPF and C# application, and I want to know if it can be ported to silverlight. Is there a tool to analyse the dependencies and tell me what I can't use, and what I can ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is not. The best way to find out is to create a Silverlight project and copy your code across, then start analysing all the build errors. It is not a great solution, but I don't know of any better way.

As an aside, there is a nice white paper that details the differences between WPF and Silverlight here:

http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

Comment: +1: I agree with "create a Silverlight project and copy your code across, then start analysing all the build errors"

Comment: I don't agree with this, if the project is not single file, it will produce no result. VS will report lot's of false-positive compile errors, due to failed dependencies on other code etc, etc and there are LOTS of compatibility errors that are run-time only, for example Delegate.BeginInvoke()  call, which is not supported in Silverlight. And it will take much more time to analyze this then reading 2 page paper about diff with WPF and thinking on your own.

Comment: I would recommend using both approaches, hence my link to the paper on WPF / Silverlight differences.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen such tool, but there is [WPF compatibility list on MSDN which i use.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#control_support_in_silverlight_vs_wpf)

Answer (score 0):

I've just remembered that when I tried to port a C# app to Linux/Mono I used [Moma analyser](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), it helps to identify issues you may have when porting a .Net application to Mono, and I know that Mono only implement Silverlight not WPF, so I will give it a try.

And you can see and change the data for what Moma consider to be implemented or not. In the Definition directory there is a 2.8-4.0-defs.zip file, inside there are 4 text files exception.txt, missing.txt, monotodo.txt, and version.txt, it is 3 lists of functions that will produce errors. So maybe someone can scrape the info about what Silverlight implements, and change the files accordingly.